# how to get basicproperties header field in pika python from rabbitmq messages?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        prop = properties
        print prop
        #print prop[1]
        #print prop[“headers”]
        #print prop.headers()
        print body
```

This is the list from prop:

```
<BasicProperties(['delivery_mode=2', "headers={'BIProto.ClickEvent': 'BIProto.ClickEvent'}", 'content_type=application/x-protobuf'])>
```

I'm able to print body and the list of basic properties. But how can I just get headers?

All the #print statements in the function error-ed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nevermind, all I had to do was print prop.headers

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Helped me.